# Getting "The permission publish_actions are not available" when I am using publish_pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have been trying to get to post on my facebook page using Facebook php sdk, and I got the error "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available", the weird thing is that I am asking for the "pages_show_list, manage_pages, publish_pages and user_photos" permissions instead. I have been trying to look for the cause but I can't find anything.

This is how I am asking for them:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
'http://localhost:8080/fbTest/fb-callback.php',
array('scope' => 'pages_show_list, manage_pages, publish_pages, user_photos'));
```

and this is my post:

```
$res = $fb->post($pageID . '/photos/', $data, $accessToken);
$post = $res->getGraphObject();
```

I am pretty new to this things and I've been reading the documentation as much as I can, but I can't find a solution. My app is not published just yet, I am still testing things with it and I have used both my admin account and a test user I made...(For the record, I managed to make the post using javascript sdk and I have no problem there, I made the post). Any idea on what could be the problem? I am pretty much using the example code facebook provides for the login and most the things I am using here. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you are using a user access token. Use a page access token

Comment: I use the next line to get the access token: $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); not sure if this one gets me a page or user token, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**
Got the solution to my case, as the mighty WizKid said, I was using a user token and not a page token.

So to get my page access token I used the following code:

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$longLivedToken = $fb->getOAuth2Client()->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedToken);
$response = $fb->sendRequest('GET', $pageID, ['fields' => 'access_token']) - 
>getDecodedBody();
$foreverPageAccessToken = $response['access_token'];
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($foreverPageAccessToken);
```

Then I made my request like this:

```
// POST request.
$res = $fb->post($pageID . '/photos/', $data, $foreverPageAccessToken);
$post = $res->getGraphObject();
```

It worked just fine for me! 
Source I found on how to get the page access token: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/785