# facebook graph api image upload is not working

Tags: node.js, fb-graph

When I try to post the image to fb page using graph api, getting the below error

(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.

But it is working fine when I try to post the message without image.

The js code will looks like below,

```
var photo_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/100788005611995/photos?"
const result = await axios.post(photo_url,{url:"url", access_token:"access_token"})
.then(res => {
    const res = res.data;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("error :",error);
});
```

I have provided all the permissions from my side. Still the response shows as need publish_actions  permissions

When I try to upload image in the fb developer tool, I am getting the error below

```
{

"error": {

 "message":"(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
  "type":"OAuthException",
  "code":200,
  "fbtrace_id":"ApakY0JK0clr-6R8YAtj5LO"}}
```

Comment: Hi @vivek, could you also add the error message the api gives you ? I mean the raw message

Comment: I am getting the below error message in the fb developer tool {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "ApakY0JK0clr-6R8YAtj5LO"
  }
}

Comment: If you could put it in your question it would be awesome. Better readability makes for faster answers.

Comment: But the error message seems pretty clear to me. This action is deprecated, have you tried what they suggest ?

Comment: yes, I need the way how to do that

Comment: Could this be of help ? It looks awefully like yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885649/getting-the-permission-publish-actions-are-not-available-when-i-am-using-publi